# Comparison of Java objects

Tags: java, object, equals

I'm new to Java, and am reading a Java book; at one point it talks about when you may want to override the built in function, equals(). For instance, if an object has a variable ID, and two objects have the same ID, you may want them to be considered to be equal. It gave example code which looks more or less like:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if((obj != null) && (obj instanceof myClass)) {
        myClass object1 = (myClass)obj;
        if(this.ID == object1.ID) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't fully understand what's going on in the third line. I'm unsure about why it's necessary and you can't just compare obj.ID and this.ID in the if() statement. My guess is that it's because obj is just declared as a generic object which may not have an ID, so you need to create a new object, object1 which is of the correct class to look at the ID.

Am I correct here? What exactly is going on in that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is almost correct: `obj` is declared to have type `Object` and `Object` can be anything, a `String` for example, it does not have to have the member named `ID`, so, you can't just look at it to compare. So, the code you quoted first check if the `obj` is of the same type (if it isn't, then you know it does not equal), and then (on the line you are asking about) *casts* it to that type.

I said, your guess was *almost* correct, because you suggested that a new object of type `myClass` is created. This is not true. The assignment `myClass object1 = (myClass)obj;` does not create any new objects, it merely makes a new variable `object1` refer to to the *same object* referred by `obj`, and tells the compiler that it should now know that that object is actually of type `myClass`.

Answer (score 4):

In your code `Object obj` is a *reference* to an Object.  The code at this point makes no assumptions about which type of Object it is.

When you do

```
myClass object1 = (myClass) obj;
```

you are casting the type of the *reference* to an object which this will either succeed because it is an instance of that type or fail throwing ClassCastException.

This creates a new *reference* but the underlying object is unchanged by this, nor is it copied.

Note: the `obj != null` check is redundant as `null` is not an `instanceof` of any class, nor does it trigger an exception. i.e.

```
Object o = null;
boolean b = o instanceof Object; // always false, never throws an exception.
```

A shorter version of this method could read.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof myClass) {
        myClass object1 = (myClass)obj;
        return ID == object1.ID;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or even

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof myClass && ID == ((myClass) obj).ID;
}
```

In Java 8 you could write

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(obj)
                   .filter(o - > o instanceof myClass)
                   .map(o -> (myClass) o)
                   .filter(m -> ID == m.ID)
                   .isPresent();
}
```

Comment: Why does the parameter have to be of type `Object` though? Couldn't it just be of type `myClass` to make the code a lot simpler?

Comment: @RobertR it would be a lot simpler but it wouldn't override `equals(Object)` instead it would overload it. i.e. it wouldn't be called in most cases. See my answer for some simpler implementations.

Answer (score 1):

On the 3rd line, no object is being created.

The first thing you need to understand about java is that there are *primitives* like `int`, `char`, `double` and *objects*, which are everything else, and **objects are always accessed by reference.**

So, `Object obj` is a reference to objects of type `Object`, and at runtime it will be referring to some object.

Then, further down, when you say `myClass object1` you are not creating any object; you are just declaring a variable called `object1` which will be referring to objects of type `myClass`.  But there is no object yet.

So, when you say `myClass object1 = (myClass)obj;` you are assigning the reference `obj` to the reference `object1`.  And since it would normally be invalid to make an assignment between different types, you are using a *type cast* (the `(myClass)` part) to tell the compiler that you know what you are doing, and you are sure that `obj` will be pointing to an object of type `myClass` at that point.  So, the compiler allows you to make the assignment.

After the assignment, both `obj` and `object1` are pointing to the same object, but the usefulness of `object1` now is that you can view this object as an object of type `myClass`, so you can access its members.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The third line is inside an if statement that says obj instanceof myClass. At that point you know that it is of type myClass. Assuming myClass has an ID like in your code then you know that both objects have ID properties and you can use those for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Research the term "Object Casting".

the `obj instanceof myClass` is making sure that `obj` is the same type as `this`. Now we know it is safe to cast and `Object obj` into a `myClass object1`

Comment: No, it's not. It's only making sure that `obj` is assignable to a `myClass` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The test for `null` is not needed, because `instanceof` is `false` for `null`s.

Just use:

```
if (obj instanceof myClass) {
```

Otherwise, your code is fine, assuming `ID` is a primitive (especially, not a `String`).